Session id undefined express
I am having trouble identifying why exactly my session id is not being set in my expressjs backend api.
When I run Postman via a post request to /provision:
const express = require("express");
require("express-async-errors");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
const createTables = require("./queries/create-tables");
const keys = require("./keys");
const cleanup = require("./queries/cleanup");

const app = express();

app.set("trust proxy", "127.0.0.1");
app.use(
  cors({
    origin:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
        ? ["<some-domain>", "<some-domain>"]
        : ["http://localhost:3000"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    keys: [keys.cookieKey],
    sameSite: "Lax",
    httpOnly: true,
    domain: "<some-domain>",
  })
);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Session:", req.session);
  if (!req.session) {
    return next(new Error("Session is not set up properly"));
  }
  next();
});

app.post("/provision", require("./provision"));
app.post("/query", require("./query"));
app.post("/reset", require("./reset"));

It appears to successfully run the provision.js logic:
const pool = require("./pool");
const createRole = require("./queries/create-role");
const createDb = require("./queries/create-db");
const { createId, validateId } = require("./queries/id");

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  let id = req.session.id;

  if (!id) {
    id = createId(8);
    req.session.id = id;
  }

  validateId(id);

  try {
    await createRole(id);
    await createDb(id);

    res.send({ status: "ok" });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw new Error("Failed to provision db");
  }
};

But when I go to run a post request on /query with the following query:
{
    "query": "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1"
}

I get:
{
    "error": "Session ID is missing"
}

After verifying session middleware is correct, the session handling appears correct, but why is the session id still not being set?
This is the code inside of query.js:
const createClient = require("./queries/create-client");
const { validateId } = require("./queries/id");
const dbExists = require("./queries/db-exists");
const touchLogin = require("./queries/touch-login");

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.session;

  console.log("Session:", id);
  if (!id) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "Session ID is missing" });
  }
  validateId(id);

  if (!(await dbExists(id))) {
    throw new Error("No database found. Reload this page.");
  }
  await touchLogin(id);

  const client = await createClient(id);

  try {
    console.log("Query:", req.body.query);
    const result = await client.query(req.body.query);

    if (Array.isArray(result)) {
      res.send(
        result.map(({ rows, fields, command, rowCount }) => ({
          command,
          rows,
          fields,
          rowCount,
        }))
      );
    } else {
      res.send([
        {
          command: result.command,
          rows: result.rows,
          fields: result.fields,
          rowCount: result.rowCount,
        },
      ]);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Query Execution Error:", err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  } finally {
    await client.end();
  }
};


Hi, It would help if you include the exact code segment in query route which causes this error - : "error": "Session ID is missing".

@WeDoTheBest4You, sorry of the late reply. I just added it.

Hi, thank you for the update. As we know, a cookie session creates a cookie on the first request, and it references the same in all subsequent requests. Therefore the cookie created in the first request must come to the client and to be saved under GoogleChrome/Developer Tools/Application/Cookies section. In fact we can see it stored over there after the first request. Can you please see if it happens in this case. Probably the cookie might be rejected by the client.

...The potential reason for the rejection as per the present configuration is the given domain value. If the domain domain: "" specified over here is a not a subdomain, then the cookie will be treated as a third-party cookie and be rejected by the Browser. If you are hosting the application and the api servers in two different hosting providers, this could be the obvious reason.

...The following two documents will be helpful to be informed if you are trying the set of two different vendors. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

@WeDoTheBest4You, When I run it in Postman, I get no cookies received from the server.

@WeDoTheBest4You, okay I think we may be getting somewhere, so at this time <some-domain> is a made up domain name I am hoping to purchase in the future. If that will not work, what can I use in its place?

So I have @WeDoTheBest4You to thank for helping me arrive at my solution. So because the domain names I am using do not actually exist yet and yet I have these domains If the domains do not exist, the user agent will fail to resolve the domain names, leading to errors when attempting to connect to those servers. As a result, the user agent won't even reach the point where cookies could be set or sent:
{
    "query": "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1"
}

If I do not have a crystal clear understanding of it, please someone feel free to edit my solution or comment and I will edit it accordingly.
The solution was to refactor my index.js file to the following:
const allowedOrigins =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? ["<some-domain>", "<some-other-domain>"]
    : ["http://localhost:3000"];

app.set("trust proxy", process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? 1 : 0);
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
      if (!origin) {
        return callback(null, true);
      }
      if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1) {
        const msg =
          "The CORS policy for this site does not allow access from the specified origin";
        return callback(new Error(msg), false);
      }
      return callback(null, true);
    },
    credentials: true,
  })
);

// app.use(
//   cors({
//     origin:
//       process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
//         ? ["<some-domain>", "<some-other-domain>"]
//         : ["http://localhost:3000"],
//     credentials: true,
//   })
// );
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    keys: [keys.cookieKey],
    sameSite: "Lax",
    httpOnly: true,
    domain: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "<some-domain>" : undefined,
  })
);

And this worked. Now the API is still not working in that now I am getting a different error, but this error has now been resolved. Thanks again.

Hi, The reason for rejecting cookies by the user agents, requires some clarity. This has been explained well here, please see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.3. The following quote addresses it:

...The user agent will reject cookies unless the Domain attribute
specifies a scope for the cookie that would include the origin
server.  For example, the user agent will accept a cookie with a
Domain attribute of "example.com" or of "foo.example.com" from
foo.example.com, but the user agent will not accept a cookie with a
Domain attribute of "bar.example.com" or of "baz.foo.example.com".

@WeDoTheBest4You, Allow me to do a check-in for understanding here.  If the domains do not exist, the user agent will fail to resolve the domain names, leading to errors when attempting to connect to those servers. As a result, the user agent won't even reach the point where cookies could be set or sent. Does that sum it up correctly?

Hi, Thank you for the followup. yes it is correct. It is sure we have conveyed  and understood the matter though the comments over here. In order to reiterate the same points with some actions, I have created a document over here - https://github.com/wedothebest4you/common. Request you may please see if it is  possible for you, it includes the same matter still it more substantiated. This is a shared git repo, please find the docx file in it.
